# XPages exit from while loop

Tags: xpages

I have a code like this below written via SSJS. When i put a break I would like to go to end of the while loop function (I have written //do staff... where i would like to go).
My question is which code i have to use it for?

```
while (docOrg!= null) 
{
   var tmpdoc = viewOrg.getNextDocument();
   if (docOrg.getItemValueString("Name")== docSta.getItemValueString("CompanyName"))
   {
    FIRM_ID = docOrg.getItemValueString("VAT");
    FIRM_NAME= docOrg.getItemValueString("InvoiceName");
    FIRM_ADDRESS=docOrg.getItemValueString("InvoiceAddress");
    FIRM_REGION=docOrg.getItemValueString("CompanyRegion") ;
    break; 
    }
    docOrg.recycle();
 docOrg = tmpdoc;
}

//do staff...
```

Comment: Your code should do what you want already: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: Don't forget parameter docOrg in `var tmpdoc = viewOrg.getNextDocument(docOrg);`

Comment: It's just a sample :) Thank you. I will not forget it.

Comment: BTW and docOrg.recycle() after the while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **break** should work as expected. It jumps to "//do staff". Although...

...there might be a better way. You walk through view to find this one company document. Performance would be much better if you'd use view index to find company's document:

```js
var viewCompanies = db.getView("Companies");
var docOrg = viewCompanies.getDocumentByKey(docSta.getItemValueString("CompanyName", true));
if (docOrg!= null) {
    FIRM_ID = docOrg.getItemValueString("VAT");
    FIRM_NAME= docOrg.getItemValueString("InvoiceName");
    FIRM_ADDRESS=docOrg.getItemValueString("InvoiceAddress");
    FIRM_REGION=docOrg.getItemValueString("CompanyRegion") ;
    docOrg.recycle();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree that your code should break as expected. However, I would change it slightly to get the recycle done - like this:

```
while (docOrg!= null) 
{
   var tmpdoc = viewOrg.getNextDocument();
   if (docOrg.getItemValueString("Name")== docSta.getItemValueString("CompanyName"))
   {
    FIRM_ID = docOrg.getItemValueString("VAT");
    FIRM_NAME= docOrg.getItemValueString("InvoiceName");
    FIRM_ADDRESS=docOrg.getItemValueString("InvoiceAddress");
    FIRM_REGION=docOrg.getItemValueString("CompanyRegion") ;
    // break;
    tmpdoc = null;   // This will ensure cleanup of docOrg - and stop loop :-) 
    }
    docOrg.recycle();
 docOrg = tmpdoc;
}
```

/John